# Mp4parser - android - cant make it work

Tags: android, mp4parser

I am a trying to make video splitting app with the help of shorten example. I am trying to implement the following project  from github. 
https://github.com/dadachi/TestMp4parser.

but the app is not working and aborting.

LogCat -

```
08-05 17:03:42.161: D/OpenGLRenderer(6834): Enabling debug mode 0 
08-05 17:03:44.934: D/do shoren starting(6834): do shoren starting 
08-05 17:03:44.944: W/dalvikvm(6834): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4151e700) 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): FATAL EXCEPTION: doShorten 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): java.lang.RuntimeException: No box object found for ftyp 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): at com.coremedia.iso.PropertyBoxParserImpl$FourCcToBox.invoke(PropertyBoxParserImpl.java:187) 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): at com.coremedia.iso.PropertyBoxParserImpl.createBox(PropertyBoxParserImpl.java:90) 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): at com.coremedia.iso.AbstractBoxParser.parseBox(AbstractBoxParser.java:87) 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): at com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile.parse(IsoFile.java:85) 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): at com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile.<init>(IsoFile.java:54) 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.container.mp4.MovieCreator.build(MovieCreator.java:32) 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): at ek.shor.shortanproj.ShortenExample$1.run(ShortenExample.java:105) 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
08-05 17:03:44.944: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): Activity ek.shor.shortanproj.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41df8010 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,192} that was originally added here 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity ek.shor.shortanproj.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41df8010 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,192} that was originally added here 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at org.bestforce.utils.Ut.ShowWaitDialog(Ut.java:40) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at ek.shor.shortanproj.ShortenExample.doShorten(ShortenExample.java:82) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at ek.shor.shortanproj.ShortenExample.shorten(ShortenExample.java:78) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at ek.shor.shortanproj.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:50) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
08-05 17:03:45.535: E/WindowManager(6834): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

The files are same as in the git hub project. please let me know what mistake I am doing what all mistakes I am making.

Comment: hey,did you find any solution of this issue ? any issue why this happened ? I am making a demo for video merging using mp4parser but getting the same issue.

Comment: yes. the example was not updated. there are some new methods so use the latest jar and take help of the latest example.

Comment: great.Can you provide me the link of the latest source ? as they have moved it from their official website.

Comment: I just saw that the examples were removed. sorry cant help you there. maybe you can look around the discussion group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TestMp4Parser example is not updated. The Mp4Parser library has been updated and there are new  methods to split and append the Videos.